# sudo access a file without sudo password

Tags: linux, sudo

I have a lab which requires me to use `sudo` to access a protected file and obtain its content.

```
linux@sudo:~$ sudo -l
Matching Defaults entries for linux on sudo:
    env_reset, mail_badpass, secure_path=/usr/local/sbin\:/usr/local/bin\:/usr/sbin\:/usr/bin\:/sbin\:/bin\:/snap/bin

User linux may run the following commands on sudo:
    (pseudo) NOPASSWD: /bin/cat

*****************************************
linux@sudo:~$ ls -al
total 24
drwxr-xr-x  2 linux  linux  4096 Jul 23 14:19 .
drwxr-xr-x  4 root   root   4096 Jul 23 14:19 ..
-rw-r--r-- 45 linux  linux   220 Apr  4 18:30 .bash_logout
-rw-r--r-- 45 linux  linux  3771 Apr  4 18:30 .bashrc
-rw-r--r-- 41 linux  linux   807 Apr  4 18:30 .profile
-rw-------  2 pseudo pseudo   22 Jun 18 15:12 secret.txt

******************************************
linux@sudo:~$ cat secret.txt
cat: secret.txt: Permission denied

******************************************
linux@sudo:~$ sudo cat secret.txt
[sudo] password for linux:
```

My aim is to open the secret.txt file but I could not find a way to bypass the request for the "linux" user password because I do not know it.

Answer (score 4):

If I get it right, this

> ```
> User linux may run the following commands on sudo:
>    (pseudo) NOPASSWD: /bin/cat
> ```

allows you (user `linux`) to run `cat` without password, **when impersonating user `pseudo`**, so

```
sudo -u pseudo /bin/cat secret.txt
```

Comment: with this, will psuedo gain access to any file which requires root access? what if we want to enable only for one file?

Comment: @knowledge_seeker `will psuedo gain access to any file which requires root access` – No. The question an the answer are about what user `linux` can do. `pseudo` can access `secret.txt` (without `sudo`) because the ownership and permissions of the file are what they are. With `sudo -u pseudo` user `linux` can impersonate `pseudo`. If you need a broader explanation then please ask a separate question (after searching for duplicates etc.) so the entire community benefits. Link to this question or answer if you think it provides the necessary context.